# `flutter install` does not install the app (iOS)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have successfully built a release version of an iOS app, but when I want to test it on my physical device with `flutter install` it doesn't install on the device. It says:

```
Installing com.cool.coolapp to iPhone...
Uninstalling old version...
(base) ➜  cool_app git:(master)
```

When running `flutter install -v` the last several lines are:

```
[ +537 ms] [ 75%] CreatingContainer
[  +17 ms] [ 80%] InstallingApplication
[  +12 ms] [ 85%] PostflightingApplication
[   +8 ms] [ 90%] SandboxingApplication
[  +12 ms] [ 95%] GeneratingApplicationMap
[ +101 ms] [100%] Installed package build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app
[  +25 ms] "flutter install" took 91,244ms.
[   +9 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 0
```

So everything looks good, but the app is not on the phone.

`flutter run` works flawlessly, not sure why `flutter install` has issues. Can anyone point me in the right direction to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to just physically connect your phone (If you are testing for IOS then your iphone) directly to your computer and run the app from your IDE. Your IDE will automatically recongnise the connected device and install the app on you phone

Comment: Through VS code is fine, but it is installed as the debug profile and it won’t run if the cable is disconnected. Can I compile release via VS code?

Comment: Go to this link and read the "Deploy to IOS device section"  : https://kobiton.com/topics/develop-deploy-and-test-flutter-apps/#:~:text=To%20deploy%20your%20Flutter%20app,Flutter%20apps%20to%20iOS%20devices.

Comment: Happy to help , have a great day